Karate robot - desktop - interact with the "value" attribute
I would like to know if you know how to interact with the "value" attribute of the DataItem element, although in the documentation it appears that to interact with the "Automation ID" attribute, a # is used and to interact with the name attribute you can go only the text or the ^ symbol, I can't find how to interact with the value attribute, I'll be attentive to your response.
Application imagen


I hope to be able to interact through the value attribute

I don't think that is possible. If this is important, I suggest you get the help of someone who knows Java and contribute an improvement to the open-source code, it should be simple.
For now, I think you have to loop through all elements and keep checking the element.value to match what you want. Or better is to find the parent somehow and then get the element etc.
